# Entites and Relationships in ER Diagram

Tags: entity-relationship

I have a question regarding ER diagram 
The question is how do we connect entities in an ER diagram 
the options are

```
1. foreign key 
2. relationship
3. primarykey
4. association
```

I know if the question was about relational diagram the answer will be: FK, but as I recall there is no FK in ER diagram and the book says the right answer is 1, so any help?